# Whatsapp API Business Verification

Tags: twilio, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm a software developer, trying to create a football tracking application for one of my client. The aim of this application is to send signals when conditions are met. These signals are sent with Twilio sandbox at the moment. Recently we upgraded to the pro version of Twilio in order to create a WhatsApp API Business sender. The Twilio phone Number is an american One but we are located in Italy.
The creation process is now stuck, because Meta is asking us to verify the business, but since my client does not have a company for this, we don't have one.

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

I already tried to link his Instagram business account but without any results.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Perhaps you should ask the people at Whatsapp business  as this seems more like a support question.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried to contact them but with no response. I wrote here because maybe someone has faced my situation.

Comment: If the people who are responsible for the product isn't responding, I'm not certain anyone here can help; but, I'll just defer to others here.  Perhaps you'll be lucky.

Answer (score 0):

If Meta won't approve it, you're in bad luck.

You could try buying an Italian number and verify this one (if that's the problem).
Or your client uses its current business entity for the verification and you migrate the logic later when the company is founded.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem Is that my client does not have a current business entity. He Is a normale employee, you mean his current job Company?

Comment: I misunderstood it. No, in this case it won't work. You could try to run it over your entity if that works but WhatsApp definitely requires a business entity and there's no way around it.